# My page occasionally snaps in the middle of the scroll

Tags: jquery-scrollify

Hope I'm not bothering the plugin creator with a stupid question.

I created a CodePen to test scrollify for my website but occasionally (1 out of 4 times) the scroll snaps between two sections and then, if I scroll again, it keeps the error going. I don't know why, but refreshing the page makes it work.

The option i'm using are:

```
$.scrollify({
section : "section.cat-section",
sectionName : "section-name",
easing: "easeOutExpo",
scrollSpeed: 1400,
offset : 0,
scrollbars: true,
setHeights: false,
overflowScroll: true,
touchScroll:true,
```

});

[Link to the CodePen](https://codepen.io/StudioCattaneo/pen/gKZXPE)

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: UPDATE - It seems like on window resize, the page starts acting normally

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue you described. Which browser are you using? One thing I did notice is that your scrollSpeed option is set to a very large number, 1400, which makes the behaviour feel quite odd, I'd recommend using a slightly smaller number.